# How to insert "File1.cshtml" into a section in main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Ok, im probably doing this wrong... But in my main _Layout I have this:

```
<div id="navigation">
            @RenderSection("Navigation")
        </div>
```

which points to this in my Index.cshtml view:

```
@section Navigation{
  <-- Need this to point to Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml -->
}
```

But I don't want to have a huge file with all my code in it, so I need to know how to point to a file called "Navigation.cshtml" inside of this section - basically so I have all my sections in separate, independent files.

I tried just doing @RenderPage("Navigation.cshtml") in the _Layout instead of @RenderSection, and that gives errors.

--EDIT--

If I add this instead of @RenderSection()

```
<div id="navigation">
          = @RenderPage("~Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml")
        </div>
```

I get this:

```
The file "~/Views/Shared/~Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml" could not be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.
```

--EDIT--

FULL _Layout.cshtml:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content">
        <!-- BANNER -->
        <div id="banner">

        </div>
        <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <div id="navigation">
         @RenderPage("Navigation.cshtml")
        </div>
        <!-- MAIN DISPLAY -->
        <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the error, add it in post

Comment: just check your path...its wrong....

Comment: Yeah that was a typo when i re-did it to get the error.  correct path i get this: I get this when I use the @RenderPage:The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Navigation"

Answer (score 9):

Try with full path of view or you can use `Html.Partial()` or `@Html.RenderPartial()`:

```
<div id="navigation">
                @RenderPage("Navigation.cshtml")
</div>
```

### Html.Partial():

```
<div id="navigation">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml")
</div>
```

### Html.RenderPartial():

```
<div id="navigation">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml"); }
</div>
```

Comment: I get this when I use the @RenderPage:The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Navigation".

Comment: can you show your _Layout.cshtml code in your question

Comment: if you write: ``@RenderPage("Navigation.cshtml")`` then what error you see?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the `@RenderSection("Navigation")` in your `_Layout` you can try below code in your view.

```
@section Navigation{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml")
}
```

OR you can change the `_Layout` as below.

```
<div id="navigation">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just to render a page "Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml" as a partial view like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
    @Html.RenderPartial("Navigation")
</div>
```