# How to share a JS script between multiple views?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, sections

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5

I have two views, `Create` and `Edit`, they both share some Javascript methods.
I'd like to find a way to write these JS methods only once, without an ugly copy / paste from a view to another

Actually, a temporary solution may be to write these methods in a separated `.js` file, and include it in both views.
This works, but **I'd like to use some Html helper provided by MVC** like `@Url.Content("")` ; so I must use a `.cshtml` file.

Is there a way to do that ? I was thinking about `@sections`, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mention about a separate script and `@section` is the solution. Otherwise write you own HtmlHelper extension.

Comment: I found this link, which is indeed helpful about `@section` and `cshtml` files : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25222178/2687153